# Windows batch file start another batch with elevated rights

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want my batch file start another batch file with elevated (admin) rights without having to accept a prompt.
I have an user (called "user") with admin rights, but if I try:

```
runas /savecred /user:user "program.bat"
```

The rights won't get elevated.
But if I try:

```
runas /savecred /user:administrator "program.bat"
```

and enter the password of "user" it says: Unknown user or wrong passphrase.

So: What do I have to do to elevate the rights only with the "user"-account?

Comment: Based on your comments, it appears that you may want to Run as administrator but bypass the security built into the Operating System. What would be the point of security if it could just be easily bypassed in a command line? If that is your question then it's not a programming issue and is off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bit overkill but if the second batch file is supposed to be **always** run as administrator you could paste following code at the start of it:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "amd64" (
    >NUL 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\config\system"
) ELSE (
    >NUL 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
)
IF '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Asking for administrative rights
    goto uac
) ELSE ( goto adm )
:uac
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\uac.vbs"
set params = %*:"=""
echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\uac.vbs"
"%temp%\uac.vbs"
del "%temp%\uac.vbs"
cls
echo Did not get administrative rights
exit
:adm
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
cls
echo Got administrative rights

::
:: YOUR CODE HERE
::
```

EDIT: It won't show the prompt and give you admin rights when you disable UAC.

Comment: It starts the other batch as admin but first after prompting. My problem is that I can't accept the prompt.

Comment: @J.B. But that's not a programming issue then. Are you sure you didn't just have a typo in the password?

Comment: no, because it starts the program... but not with elevated rights.

Comment: If the %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% is 64bit then why do you think running an executable in the SysWOW64 directory would be correct?

Comment: @Compo sorry but I don't really know what you mean

Comment: On a 64bit Windows OS you would run cacls.exe from the System32 directory

Comment: This works when you disable UAC. It won't show the prompt then. Thank you.

Comment: @J.B. The code is still not correct, _accepted or otherwise_.

Comment: @Compo edit it to make it correct please or provide a correct answer.

Comment: @J.B. Thank you for the informations! Also, Compo If your goal is it to bypass the UAC Prompt then I am afraid I can't help you. And I think no one on here will.